# 405 from Angular

Tags: angular, cors, asp.net-web-api2

I'm having what I believe is a CORS issue, but I'm struggling to solve it.  I need to allow access from everywhere so in my Web API 2 service I added this to web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
    <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

I'm not entirely sure why the handlers stuff is there but the group I inherited this project from said I had to have it for CORS stuff.

I also verified that the IIS server isn't filtering any verbs.

When I then run my angular app locally via 'npm run start' and it connects to the webservice, I end up getting back a 405 error when I try to do my post.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) for enabling CORS for your asp.net webapi 2. Once CORS is enabled you should be able to POST using Angular app.

Here are steps:

1. Install Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors NuGet Package
2. Add `config.EnableCors();` in `WebApiConfig.Register` method
3. Add `EnableCors` attribute on action method or controller based on your requirements

Comment: I'm getting this error: ` The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values '*, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.` when I tried to enable via `config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));`

Comment: After enabling CORS globally are you setting it on contoller or action method as well? Also, ensure you remove the web.config changes you were trying before using this Nuget Package

Comment: No. One method doesn’t send the header at all. A couple send it with two stars.

Comment: You removed web.config changes related to custom headers?